# How to decrypt a large AES encrypted data with openssl command?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I want to decrypt large AES encrypted data:

Encrypted data: `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` (base64 encoded)

Key: `uHe2MCmggLlugpGBiMVuXTck7OT8Nk8g` (base64 encoded)

Cipher: AES-256-CBC

IV: `LNP8U7pc6GjxzxAtgw4s3A==` (base64 encoded)

I try to use this command for it:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d  -in data.enc -out data.dec -K $key -iv $iv
```

In $key and $iv i decoded from encoded values this way

```
iv=$( cat response.json | jq .iv -r | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' )
```

But i have crashed data like this

```
^GÌ<8a>û)F"PEi~^K±jÔ^AcWSM
23NDwSOqovXSFGNfy3WatkCreYRd7kcWSM";
```

Comment: Your key has 24 bytes so it can't be AES 256 thus AES 192 sees to be more likely.

Comment: Key it's just a random string..)

Comment: If you try to use AES256 with an AES192 key it will not work or depending on the encrypting implementation key stretching or key generation algorithm may be applied. This can be the reason why decryption fails. So you have to know how it was encrypted to properly decrypt it.

Comment: But it works on the small data string, why?

Comment: If it works with small but not with large data you may have selected the wrong cipher mode (cbc).